# Use non conda python with keras

Tags: python, r, keras

I'm trying to use `keras` in R but unfortunately keep getting

```
Error: Python module keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/N~1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
version:        3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.2
keras:          [NOT FOUND]
```

I have installed `keras` using `pip install` but checking with `reticulate` returns FALSE. Here is a summary of the code I've ran

```
reticulate::py_discover_config("keras")
```

This returns:

```
keras:          C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.p

python versions found: 
 C:/Users/N~1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe
 C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
 C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\\python.exe
 E:\Pyconda\python.exe
 E:\Anaconda\python.exe
 E:\Anaconda\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
```

I think(thought) the problem is(was) with having several python paths, so I set:

```
use_python("C:/Users/N~1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe")
```

I have read up on several questions and GitHub issues but have unfortunately failed to solve this issue.
**Question**:

How can I correctly use a specific "python"?!